# Traciality of compressions of von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, trace, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\phi_1$ be a linear functional on a von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{A}.$ (I need the result in particular for $\Pi_1$-factors), satisfying traciality. With "traciality" I mean the following:  For $A,B\in\mathcal{A}$ we have $$\phi_1(A B)=\phi_1(B A).$$ Let further $p\in\mathcal{A}$ be a projection and $M_p:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow p \mathcal{A} p$ be the compression of $\mathcal{A}$ with respect to $p.$ Define a linear functional $\phi_2$ on $\mathcal{A}$ by $\phi_2 (A):=\phi_1 (p A p)$ for $A\in\mathcal{A}.$
My question is: Does the traciality of $\phi_1$ imply that $$\phi_2 (A B) = \phi_2(B A)?$$ Do I need additional assumptions for this to hold? Does anyone know a source where this might be covered?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: For II$_1$-factors this follows from uniqueness of the trace

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have no relation between $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ so no, of course there is no implication.

But, more importantly, the relation you want does not even hold for $\phi_1$. For instance in $M_2(\mathbb C)$ (but you can easily lift this example to any II$_1$-factor), let 
$$
p=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 2\\3&4\end{bmatrix},\ \ B=\begin{bmatrix} 5&6\\7&8\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(pABp)=19\ne23=\operatorname{Tr}(pBAp). 
$$

---

In the case where $\phi_2(A)=\tfrac1{\phi_1(p)}\phi_1(pAp)$ (the factor to normalize $\phi_2$ so that it is unital if $\phi_1$ is) then yes, $\phi_2$ is a trace on $p\mathcal Ap$. If $A,B\in p\mathcal Ap$, then $A=pAp$, $B=pBp$, so 
$$
\phi_2(AB)=\tfrac1{\phi_1(p)}\,\phi_1(pAp\,pBp)=\tfrac1{\phi_1(p)}\,\phi_1(pBp\,pAp)=\phi_2(BA). 
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, you are completely right. I meant to define $\phi_2$ on $\mathcal{A}$ by $\phi_2 (A) := \phi_1 (pAp)$ for $A\in\mathcal{A}.$ The way I wrote it did not constiute any connection between the two traces. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Then $\phi_2$ is a trace, but you still need to be careful with the way you wrote the equality. It's true if $A,B\in p\mathcal Ap$, but not in general if $A,B\in \mathcal A$

Comment: Thank you. I changed the definition of $\phi_2$ accordingly. This should be fine now, right?

Comment: Yes, $\ \ \ \ \ \ $